# C#: How do I terminate a socket before Socket.BeginReceive calls back?

Tags: c#, tcp, sockets, connection

I have a server that receives connection requests from clients. This server makes use of the asynchronous `Socket.BeginReceive` and `Socket.EndReceive` method. The code is pretty similar to the code found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx).

In my case, after calling `Socket.BeginReceive` I need a timeout such that if the client hangs on to the connection but does not transmit any data at all for a fixed amount of time, I need to terminate the connection.

- How do I go about terminating the
  connection in this scenario?
- What is the best way of coding a
  timer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just call the socket's `Close()` method.  The callback method will run pretty quickly after that, you'll get an `ObjectDisposedException` when you call the `EndReceive()` method.  Be prepared to catch that exception.

You probably don't want to block the thread that called `BeginReceive`, you'll need a `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer` to detect the timeout.  Its callback should call `Close()`.  Beware of the inevitable race-condition this causes, the timer's callback will run if the response was received a microsecond before the timer expired.  You'll close the socket, even though you got a good response.  The next call to `BeginReceive()` will fail immediately.

Comment: Do you mean that the callback method will still run after the socket's close method is called?

Comment: If a BeginReceive() is pending: yes.  It *always* has to be paired with an EndReceive() call.  You can't avoid the callback.

Comment: I've been looking for the solution to this issue all day. Thanks for your in depth response. I never expected an Exception to be expected but then again I'm pretty new to .NET programming.

Answer (score 7):

I know this thread is pretty old but I just encountered the same problem and I was not satisfied by the answer given here (or anywhere else by that matter).

A better solution to cancel a pending `Socket.BeginReceive` is to call `Socket.Shutdown` and not `Socket.Close`. This way the asynch handler is raised "normally", and a call to `Socket.EndReceive` returns 0 --> instead of throwing an ugly expected-exception.
You should always have an

```
if (Socket.EndReceive() > 0) {
  //Do something
} else {
  //Socket has been shut down (either by you or the other end of the connection)
  //Now it's "safe" to call Socket.Close
  Socket.Close();
}
```

so you don't even need to adjust your asynch-callback to handle the manual cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN article on [Socket.BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw.aspx) it states

> To cancel a pending BeginReceive, call the Close method.

Comment: And to quote for the documentation for the Close method:  "For connection-oriented protocols, it is recommended that you call Shutdown before calling the Close method. This ensures that all data is sent and received on the connected socket before it is closed."

Answer (score 0):

You can Receive some initial data asynchronously and then make synchronous Receive for rest of the data and rely on ReceiveTimeout to disconnect the client. You can use Socket.Close to forcefully disconnect client.

But if you want to use async Receive only, then you can use timers and reset them on EndReceive. If it elapse you can disconnect the client forcefully.

But I think the first approach is better.