# How to release ports and stop listening after sending a message with the UdpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp, udpclient

I have two UDP clients:

```
UdpClient _udpReceiver
```

and

```
UdpClient _udpSender
```

For receiving a message I'm using `_udpReceiver.BeginReceive(...);`

And for sending: `_udpSender.BeginSend(data, data.Length, new AsyncCallback(StopCallback, _udpSender);`

What I'm trying to achieve is to stop any sending and receiving and somehow unbind the ports which _udpReceiver and _udpSender are using. But with no success:

```
  private void StopCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
       try
        {
            UdpClient client = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState;
            client.EndSend(ar);     
            client.Close(); //app crashes here   
            _udpSender.Client.Close(); //and here              
            _udpReceiver.Client.Close(); //and here too
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            //and this one is never getting caught
        }
    }
```

---

**UPD: attached link to a project which reproduces the crash**

http://1drv.ms/1kWWJKA

Comment: Can't reproduce the first crash. The second is normal: you can't close `_udpSender.Client` *again*, you've just closed it. The fact that you don't enter the `catch` is also normal, the crashes are `NullReferenceException`. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: What do you mean by "using a debugger"? I set a breakpoint into the catch block and it was never hit. Neither `Exception` nor `NullReferenceException` were hit as well.

Comment: In Output window of VS I can see that It was an ObjectDisposedException but I'm unable to catch it before the app crashes. I even tried to set global catch on the whole app, it did not helped.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your scenario. Please post the minimal example, short but complete, which reproduces it.

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1kWWJKA Please press 'Start listen' and then 'Send message and stop' and it will crash.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662553/how-to-abort-sockets-beginreceive I believe that closing a socket is what I need but still I'm unable to catch these exceptions and my app just crashes...

Comment: Try to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019997/udpclient-receiveasync-correct-early-termination/41041601#comment69291144_41041601