# C# Socket Server how to cancel thread that is stuck at socket.accept()

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I am working on writing a really simple RPC library using C# and sockets for a class assignment. I have the send feature working which is nice but I am testing how my KillServer function works. I have implemented a lot of threading in the Server library and I am not sure that I have gotten down the proper way of canceling and softly killing the threads.

My StartServerThread method:

```
public void StartServer()
        {
            ServerThread = new Task(()=> 
            {
                _Socket.Listen(100);
                // Enter a loop waiting for connection requests
                // Or because I am RDM I don't need connections
                while (!_TokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var newClient = _Socket.Accept();

                        _Clients.Add(newClient, ClientThread(newClient));
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Canceled");
                    }
                }


                foreach (var client in _Clients)
                {
                    client.Key.Disconnect(false);
                }

            },_TokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            ServerThread.Start();
        }
```

My problem here is once the thread hits the _Socket.Accept() line it is blocking. So even if I call Cancel on the TokenSource the thread is still stuck at that line and doesn't nicely end. I am having a hard time designing this library in such a way that uses threading and allows good performance with multiple clients connected.

Comment: Have you tried a non-blocking socket? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.blocking?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: have you tried to call _Socket.Close() ? this full close the listener and release all resources

Comment: Look at [Thread.Interrupt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.interrupt?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Thread_Interrupt) method , and Close method of socket both of them unblock clientThread

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities how to solve this problem. You can use already mentioned non-blocking sockets or you can use asynchronous functions like `Socket.​Begin​Accept`. Here is some [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example) from MSDN.

The important code follows.

```
while (true)
{  
    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
    allDone.Reset();  

    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
    allDone.WaitOne();  
}
```

Here the manual reset event `allDone` is set in callback function when new TCP connection is accepted that wakes up while cycle in previous code to call `Socket.​Begin​Accept` once again.

```
public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)    
{  
    // Signal the main thread to continue.  
    allDone.Set();  
    // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
    Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;  
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
    ...
```

Now, if you want to stop your thread from accepting new calls you can 'misuse' event `allDone` and set it to wake up your 'BeginAccept' thread that is waiting for event `allDone`. Then the 'BeginAccept' thread can check `TokenSource.IsCancellationRequested` if loop cycle should continue or exit.

```
// MODIFY while contition.
while (!_TokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
{  
    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
    allDone.Reset();  

    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
    allDone.WaitOne();  
}
```

And here is the code you call when you want to exit 'BeginAccept' thread.

```
 // Don't continue with the while cycle.
 _TokenSource.Cancel();

 // Wake up thread calling BeginAccept().
 allDone.Set()
```

Another possibility is using 2 instances of events. Something like this.

```
// Declared somewhere to be accessible from both threads.
ManualResetEvent exitThread;


while (true)
{  
    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
    allDone.Reset();  

    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

    // Wait until a connection is made or thread is exiting 
    if (WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[]{exitThread,allDone})==0)
    {
        break;      
    }
}
```

And while cycle from second thread can now be stopped by executing.

```
exitThread.Set();
```

Code `WaitHandle.WaitAny()` is waiting until any of 2 events is signalized and when `exitThread` is signalized (`WaitHandle.Wait()` returns 0) it jumps out of loop.

But now another problem arises. Because you have already called `Socket.​Begin​Accept` when you call `Socket.​Close` - callback `AcceptCallback` is fired. And because socket has already been closed, method `Socket.EndAccept` will throw `ObjectDisposedException`. So you must catch and ignore this exception in callback method `AcceptCallback`. Here are more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662553/how-to-abort-sockets-beginreceive) about `Socket.​Begin​Receive` which applies to `Socket.​Begin​Accept` too.

With the arrival of .NET Task library there is another maybe more elegant solution by using extension method [Accept​Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions.acceptasync?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_SocketTaskExtensions_AcceptAsync_System_Net_Sockets_Socket_) but I can't find some nice example on Internet. And I personally prefer 'old-school' BeginXYZ()-EndXYZ() asynchronous model - maybe because I'm too old...

Answer (score 0):

Create local connection in the same application to unlock this call:

```
Socket handler = listener.Accept();
```

Code will look like this:

```
Socket clientToUnlockAccept = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

clientToUnlockAccept.Connect(localEndPoint)
```